# Would potential astronauts on Titan be in danger of being blown away?

Tags: atmosphere, spacesuits, titan

Titan (the largest moon of Saturn) has a thicker and denser atmosphere than the Earth and a surface gravity of less than 1/7 that of the Earth. So potential visitors would be very light and what would happen if a storm comes? I think they might easily be blown off the ground by too strong winds, unless they wear massive enough suits. If they'd set up any items on Titan's surface these items might be in danger to be blown away too if they aren't tighted strongly enough. Is it possible to make up massive enough suits that astronauts won't get blown away off the surface but that are wearable? Would suits that are ~7.2 times heavier (so that they have an Earth-like weight) be good for Titanean visitors? Actually, Titanean astronauts wouldn't need pressurized suits at all there. Is that an advantage for massive enough clothes to not get blown away?

Comment: Below 7 km the wind speed is low.

Comment: Is it possible to make weighted suits? Sure. Is that high on the list of problems for sending a human to titan? No, not really. I'd say temperature, volatile elements and other things are much more of an issue than wind. Maybe focus your question more on "are wind speeds on the surface of titan a potential issue" rather than on "would a weighted suit help a potentially non-existent problem" because the former is more objective :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tl, dr:  With some care, high surface winds can be avoided.  They seem to occur only once per fifteen years or so as Titan is in equinox.  If we avoid the storms, which would likely be done anyway to simplify landing the craft and taking off again, surface winds will not be a problem at all.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_of_Titan):

> Surface winds are normally low (<1 meter per second). Recent computer simulations indicate that the huge dunes of soot like material raining down from the atmosphere in the equatorial regions may instead be shaped by rare storm winds that happen only every fifteen years when Titan is in equinox.[1] The storms produce strong downdrafts, flowing eastward at up to 10 meters per second when they reach the surface. In late 2010, the equivalent of early Spring in Titan's northern hemisphere, a series of methane storms were observed in Titan's equatorial desert regions.[2]
>
> Due to the eccentricity of Saturn's orbit, Titan is about 12% closer to the sun during the southern hemisphere summer, making southern summers shorter but hotter than northern summers. This asymmetry may contribute to topological differences between the hemispheres - the northern hemisphere has many more hydrocarbon lakes.[3] Titan's lakes are largely placid, with few waves or ripples; however, Cassini has found evidence of increasing turbulence during the northern hemisphere summer, suggesting that surface winds may strengthen during certain times of the Titanian year.[4] Waves and ripples have also been seen by Cassini.[5]

The "waves and ripples" on the northern lakes cited in References 4 and 5 offer less than meets the eye, sonce they are also sensitized to low wind speeds due to the low(er than Earth) Titanian gravity.  Reference 5, upon perusal, indicates the rippling of the Titanian lakes again corresponds to wind speeds less than 1m/s.

Cited references:

1.
"Violent Methane Storms on Titan May Explain Dune Direction". SpaceRef. April 15, 2015. Retrieved April 19, 2015.  [Link](http://spaceref.com/saturn/violent-methane-storms-on-titan-may-explain-dune-direction.html)

2.
"Cassini Sees Seasonal Rains Transform Titan's Surface". NASA. March 17, 2011. Retrieved January 20, 2018.  [Link](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/cassini/whycassini/cassini20110317.html)

3.
Aharonson, Oded (November 2009). "Titan's Lakes". California Institute of Technology. Archived from the original on April 15, 2018. Retrieved January 30, 2019.  [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180415114835/http://web.gps.caltech.edu/%7Eoa/titanlakes.shtml)

4.
Boyle, Rebecca (March 5, 2016). "Summer on Titan may make its lakes ripple with waves". New Scientist. No. 3063. Retrieved January 30, 2019.  [Link](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2079284-summer-on-titan-may-make-its-lakes-ripple-with-waves/)

5.
Klotz, Irene (March 23, 2014). "Cassini Spies Wind-Rippled Waves on Titan". Space.com. Retrieved January 30, 2019.  [Link](https://www.space.com/25186-cassini-spies-titan-waves.html).

Comment: "Charnay said direct observation by Cassini would be the way to confirm his hypothesis. Unfortunately, the Cassini mission will end in 2017 and Titan's next equinox is not until 2023." Pioneer only took 3 years to reach Saturn, was wondering if someone made a proposal for possibly launching a small probe for a study on this (even if it's just a proposal). May ask a follow up when I poke around a bit more. Thanks for some of the good reads in the sources there.